# Group by unit and show the unit that has the most recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm having a difficult time writing a query for a personal project. I have some data for a housing community that lists all the historical statuses of each unit. Each status, uniquely defined by the column "HMY", represents a period of time that a resident stayed in the unit. You can see in dtStart when a resident began living in a unit and dtEnd when a resident left the unit. If dtEnd is NULL it means that the resident is currently living there. Since these are historical statuses, there are multiple rows for each unit. I'm hoping to write a query that lists all of the most recent units. Here is a snapshot of what my current table looks like:

[image: Table: [Unit_Status]]

In pseudo-code I'd like to group by units that have the most recent record (so the highest value of hMy or even when dtEnd is NULL).

Is there anyone with the wisdom to help me out with this?

Thank you!!

Comment: Where dtEnd IS NULL?

Comment: @SeanLange I dont think that is quite right. A currently vacant unit would have no record in a query written that way

Comment: @pquest Exactly the issue!

Comment: @Walker I have you covered, I just need a few minutes to take care of something else before I put an answer together

Comment: Here's an idea, add another boolean column to indicate that the unit is occupied. Fill those with true where dtEnd id NULL. Now, fill dtEnd with sysdate where dtEnd is NULL. You will still retain information about current occupancy. Thenjust run a simple window query to get your results. Something like `PARTITION BY hUnit ORDER BY dtEnd DESC`

Comment: Apparently I was missing something because the question was sufficiently vague.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you are looking for. Can you provide sample output?

Comment: @Walker did one of these work for you? If so, please be sure to mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH t1 (property, hunit) AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    property,
    hunit
  FROM table
)
SELECT
  t1.property,
  t1.hunit,
  highest.hmy,
  highest.dtstart,
  highest.dtend
FROM t1

CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP(1)
    hmy,
    dtstart,
    dtend
  FROM table t

  WHERE
    t.property = t1.property
    AND t.hunit = t1.hunit

  ORDER BY
    hmy DESC

) highest
```

This sql first gets a distinct list of all properties and units (the WITH clause). Then it uses CROSS Apply to join the record with the largest hmy back onto the property and hunit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ROW_NUMBER() to partition by hUnit and order by hMy in descending order.  Then just select the first row, which contains the highest hMy, from each partition.

```
SELECT hMy,Property,hUnit,dtStart,dtEnd
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY hUnit ORDER BY hMy DESC) RowID,hMy,Property,hUnit,dtStart,dtEnd
    FROM MyTable
) a
WHERE RowID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution using a subquery in the where clause may look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE (hMy, hUnit) in (
                       SELECT
                           MAX(hMy),
                           hUnit
                       FROM TABLE
                       GROUP BY
                           hUnit
                       )
```

This gets you the entire row for the hUnit with the highest hMy for that hUnit.